# Crop the string only after html tag

Tags: php

My issue is, if the string contains an html tag, then the string should becropped in between the html elements. This is my code. I want to cut the string if string length is greater than 80. When I try to do this string is cropped in between these tags. This will affected css style issue. So string cropping should be only after end of the html tag.

```
<?php 
      echo $word='hello good morning<span class="em emj2"></span> <span class="em emj13"></span>      <span class="em emj19"></span> <span class="em emj13"></span> hai';
$a=strlen($word);    
if($a>80)
 {
  echo substr($word,0,80);
 }
else
    echo $word;
?>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: after cropping my string is 'hello good morning<span class="em emj2"'.but i want 'hello good morning<span class="em emj2"></span>'.

Comment: So, in other words: you want to cut the string at 80 characters, or more if 80 characters breaks up the html tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform a second edit and use strrpos to find the last > and see if it is before the last < in the resulting string.

If so, cut back to before the last < to ensure you don't have a partial tag inclusion.

```
<?PHP
echo $word='hello good morning<span class="em emj2"></span> <span class="em emj13"></span><span class="em emj19"></span> <span class="em emj13"></span> hai';
echo "\n";
$a=strlen($word);
echo strlen($word);
echo "\n";
if($a>80) {
        $b=substr($word,0,80);
        echo "$b\n";
        $end=strrpos($b,'>');
        $start=strrpos($b,'<');
        echo "> is $end from the end, < is $start from the end\n";
        if($start > $end){
                echo "cutting '$b' down to $end characters (+1 to keep the '>')\n";
                $b=substr($b,0,$end+1);
        }
        echo "$b\n";
}
else {
        echo $word."\n";
}
```

This will not stop you from separating the closing `</tag>` from a `<tag>`, but it will stop you from breaking a tag in the middle.

Comment: Modified from strrchr to strrpos (sorry for the mixup). Also posted an example designed for command line (source view).

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find if you've broken your html but cutting the string reliably with the method you're trying.
How would you detect cases like this?

```
Hello good morning<span class='whatever'><div class='somethingelse'>blah</div>
```

You're going to need to employ the use of a [HTML](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) [Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Find where you want to cut the string and check that against your HTML Parser to see if you're inside an unclosed element.